# http async response for large response

Tags: android, http, asynchronous, nio, large-data

I'm familiar with android HTTPURLConnection and apache HTTPConnection classes and the way they work (they are all synchronous, but I can live with that).

I have a large response with many lines of data comming from the server. It's a JSON response and I can display the data partially before I parsed all the response. Some json parsers allow that (like xcers allows for xml). Do the callbacks and methods related to the two classes mentioned above allow it?  When I get the response from HTTPURLConnection upon opening input stream and read, do I open the stream when **ALL** the data is already there?  Or can I open and read it and more that should follow?

Also, is there any http method on android that works with NIO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With HttpClient, when you open the response stream like this:

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(new URI(url));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
```

and start reading, you actually start the downloading and you get new bytes as soon as these are received. You don't wait for everything to get downloaded to start reading.

As far as I know the HttpClient that is bundled with Android is not based on NIO. I don't know of any alternative that does so.

Comment: as i stated in my questions i know the code above, if you say the InputStream is updated than that's my answer however, let's say it takes a bit of time (slow server) and i reached the end of my stream, no new data yet arrived, so my stream.avialable or stream.read() will return 0 and -1 respectivly, how can i know when new data is avialabe (this is why i asked about NIO).

Comment: no better response arrived so i'll accept your answer, though it's only partial. 10x anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all of the possible solutions in Ladlestein's comment, there's the simple answer of wrapping all that in an `AsyncTask`. Here is [a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Service) demonstrating doing an `HTTP request` using `HttpClient` in an `AsyncTask`.

Comment: mike the aync part, as i allready said in my question is NOT the real problem , i don't use AsyncTask but aService with my own connection queue that has several threads that each if available will be able to run one runnable and call a callback or intent or will broadcast once finished (error or ok response) so your answer doesn't really add new information for me.